# Add new format to civicrm_entity

Tags: civicrm-entity, git

I would like to add a new format to civicrm_entity. I have tried to create an issue and patch in Github, but I am not experienced so I am stuck what to do next.

Is anyone able to give me a push?

https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/civicrm_entity/issues/334

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are mostly there.  In the issue link, there is a link to your patch.  Click that and you get to your code diff with a 'Create pull request' button at the top.  Click that, fill in the information about your change and hit the next 'Create pull request' button.

That will send the request to the repo maintainers who (hopefully) will merge it or request further changes.

Comment: Thanks, performed the steps and hope it will be committed.